# Swap Ctrl/Caps Lock not working in VirtualBox 4.3.16

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox

Until now my keyboard mapping in Kubuntu 14.04 has worked seamlessly in the guest OS of Windows 7, which I run in VirtualBox. But after the upgrade to VirtualBox version 4.3.16 r95972 the swapping of Ctrl & Caps Lock is not respected. Any ideas for fixing this - or is it a known bug in the new VirtualBox version?

Thanks!

-HStovring

Update: I found the AutoHotKey program, which allows you to do the swapping inside Windows (plus a bunch of other stuff). After installing the program I placed a simple text file in my C:\Users\username\ directory with this content:

+Capslock::Capslock ; make shift+Caps-Lock the Caps Lock toggle
Capslock::Control   ; make Caps Lock the control button

Comment: Any chance it is related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060354/caps-lock-stopped-working-after-an-update?.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same version of Virtual Box.  I was able to work around the problem by running ctrl2cap.exe in Windows from the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx) tool suite.