# Caps lock stopped working after an update

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, capslock

For some reason, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> stopped working on my machine. Not only on the laptop keyboard, but on any connected keyboard as well. I'm using 18.04 on a Dell XPS 15 9560.

It worked perfectly until a few days ago and it stopped working after rebooting when I just had done a regular system update.

Comment: Try using the tweak tool to check and set the caps lock behavior.   Specifically check: `Keyboard & Mouse->Additional Layout Options->Caps lock behavior` to see if the setting there is what you want.

Comment: @MartinW Wow, thanks for pointing that out! I've been looking over there but missed the `Additional Layout Options` button.  Now I set it to `Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization of alphabetic characters`, which I suppose it was before. Thanks again!

Comment: @MartinW Your comment seems to have helped. Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems with a KDE VM that had been working for years, before a VMWare update, and after trying MANY possibilities within KDE, to no avail, turned off the VMWare's enhanced keyboard and everything returned to normal.